# Reversed pointer in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a web application in which I need the cursor to be horizontaly reversed (flipped right to left) when I hover one element like in *Microsoft Word* or *Notepad++* :

[image: reversed pointer]

And I didn't found it in the pointer list.

I know I can use this :

```
#reversedCursor:hover
{
    cursor: url("pointer.png"), pointer;
}
```

But the cursor location will be at the top left corner of the image, and I want it at the top right corner.

I don't want something hard to implement with changing elements positions, or other things like that.

To sum up : is it possible to change the pointer to the reversed one, or is it possible to set the cursor position somewhere in the cursor image ? If yes, can you give me an example ?

I hope you understand what I need.

Comment: Well, it could answer one question. But is there any way I can directly set the reverse pointer ?

Comment: @Whitebird Is that a cut and paste comment? I seem to read those words everywhere on SO. If you think it is a duplicate flag it as such.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to put my cursor into a special div, but it might be an emergency option.

Comment: I think it may be the only way

Comment: Changing the `direction` property like `direction: rtl;` might trigger the browser to switch the pointer automatically.

Comment: @Anthony Your solution doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/y7btbp5g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the position of the cursor hotspot using css3:

```
cursor: [ <uri> [ <x> <y> ]? , ]* <system>;
```

so in your case something like:

```
cursor:  url("pointer.png") 25 0, pointer;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But is there any way I can just have the reversed pointer ? (If I don't get any other answer, I will accept your answer.)

Comment: I don't think there is a native reversed cursor